# C++: will this disk seek take a very large performance hit?

Tags: c++, io

I am using the STL fstream utilities to read from a file. However, what I would like to do is is read a specified number of bytes and then seek back some bytes and read again from that position. So, it is sort of an overlapped read. In code, this would look as follows:

```
ifstream fileStream;
fileStream.open("file.txt", ios::in);

size_t read_num = 0;
size_t windows_size = 200;
while (read_num < total_num)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    size_t num_bytes_read = fileStream.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    read_num += num_bytes_read - 200;
    filestream.seekg(read_num);
}
```

This is the not the only way to solve my problem but will make multi-tasking a breeze (I have been looking at other data structures like circular buffers but that will make multitasking difficult). I was wondering if I can have your input on how much of a performance hit these seek operations might take when processing very large files. I will only ever use one thread to read the data from file.

The files contain large sequence of texts only characters from the set {A,D,C,G,F,T}. Would it also be advisable to open it as a binary file rather than in text mode as I am doing?

Because the file is large, I am also opening it in chucks with the chuck being set to a 32 MB block. Would this be too large to take advantage of any caching mechanism?

Comment: This is platform dependent. On linux I would expect the caching/buffering mechanism to cause this to have a low cost. Can you benchmark?

Comment: I only have access to a mac, but I will try. Thanks for the linux feedback. I am guessing mac will have similar performance.

Comment: If only one thread is reading the file, then why would using a circular buffer cause an issue for multi-threading?

Comment: The file system cache ensures that doesn't cost anything.  Seeking in a text stream is however a *very* questionable practice.

Comment: @HansPassant Why is that? Questionable practice i.e.

Comment: Because a text stream contains characters, not bytes.  A character can be between 1 and 4 bytes.  You'll seek into the middle of a utf-8 sequence for example.

Comment: Why? I've never yet seen a file that couldn't be processed in one pass. In 44 years.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, my file only contains certain characters like A, C, G. Is there a better stream reader for this?

Comment: @EJP: My file is 10s of GB in length and the underlying algorithm needs overlapped access to the data.

Comment: @Luca: that should go into the question, not in a comment. And you should explain what are these files (what kind of content: video, ...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I edited the question now.

Comment: @EJP: some files are better processed in *two* passes. Assembler are using two passes since the 1950s, and with good reasons. I am coding something which read a textual file in two passes.

Comment: @Luca: next time you ask a question here, please give more context immediately (and explain what kind of software are you coding!) not after have been asked for it. Context (in your case, kind and size of data, and something about your application) and motivations matters a lot to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That was my bad. Id id not know this would have such an impact on the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On POSIX systems (notably Linux, and probably MacOSX), the C++ streams are based on lower primitives (often, [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)) such as [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and the implementation will [buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) the data (in the standard C++ library, which would call [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) on buffers of several kilobytes) and the kernel generally keeps recently accessed pages in its [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). Hence, practically speaking, most not too big files (e.g. files of few hundred megabytes on a laptop with several gigabytes of RAM) are staying in RAM (once they have been read or written) for a while. See also [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html).

As commented by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant), reading in the middle a textual file could be errorprone (in particular, because an UTF8 character may span on several bytes) if not done very carefully.

<sup>Notice that for a C ([fopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)) or [C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes) point of view, textual files and binary files differ notably on how they handle end of lines.</sup>

If performance matters a lot for you, you could use directly low level systems calls like [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) but then be careful to use wide enough buffers (typically of several kilobytes, e.g. 4Kbytes to 512Kbytes, or even several megabytes). Don't forget to use the returned read or written byte count (some IO operations can be partial, or fail, etc...). Avoid if possible (for performance reasons) to repeatedly [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) only a dozen of bytes. You could instead memory-map the file (or a segment of it) using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (before `mmap`-ing, use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to get metadata information, notably file size). And you could give *advices* to the kernel using [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) or (for file mapped into virtual memory) [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html). Performance details are heavily system dependent (file system, hardware -SSD and hard-disks are different!, system load).

At last, you should consider using some higher-level library on binary files such as indexed files à la [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or the [sqlite](http://sqlite.org) library, or consider using real databases such as [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org), [MonogDB](http://mongodb.org/) etc.

Apparently, your files contain [genomics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genomics) information. Probably you don't care about end-of-line processing and could open them as binary streams (or directly as low-level Unix file descriptors). Perhaps there already exist free software libraries to parse them. Otherwise, you might consider a two-pass approach: a first pass is reading *sequentially* the entire file and remembering (in C++ containers like `std::map`) the interesting parts and their offsets. A second pass would use direct access. You might even have some preprocessor converting your genomics file into SQLITE or GDBM files, and have your application work on these. You probably should avoid opening these files as text (but just as binary file) because end-of-line processing is useless to you.

On a 64 bits system, if you handle only a *few* files (not thousands of them at once) of several dozens of gigabytes, memory mapping (with `mmap`) them should make sense, then use `madvise` (but on a 32 bits system, you won't be able to `mmap` the entire file).

Comment: So if I am reading file in chunks? is it advisable to keep these chunks to a few kilobytes rather than 16-32 MB, which is what I was thinking.

Comment: no, megabytes chunk is ok. But then, you should open a *binary* file, not a *textual* file.

Comment: Ok, and then I can convert the binary representation to text, I guess? Is that an ok approach?

Comment: I don't know what that means for you, and I have no idea what kind of files are you processing. You really should edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Plasibly, yes. Whenever you seek, the cached file data for that file is (likely to be) discarded, causing extra overhead of, at least, a system call to fetch the data again.

Assuming the file isn't enormous, it MAY be a better choice to read the entire file into memory (or, if you don't need portability, use a memory mapped file, at which point caching of the file content is trivial - again assuming the entire file fits in (virtual) memory).

However, all this is implementation dependent, so measuring performance of each method would be essential - it's only possible to KNOW these things for a given system by measuring, it's not something you can read about and get precise information on the internet (not even here on SO), because there are a whole bunch of factors that affect the behaviour.

Comment: Why would a (not too far back) seek cause cache data to be discarded?

Comment: Most not too big files (e.g. a few hundred megabytes on a machine with several gigabytes of RAM, as most laptops have) fit in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)

Comment: @jepio: Because on average seek backwards are relatively rare, and it's much easier to simply discard the cached data than to figure out where we should go to. (Yes, the OS cache will still be there, most likely, as that basically caches "all free memory" as file content recently read)